# Активация модуля mod_v8 для FreeSwitch 10 в Debian 11

Tags: javascript, debian, модули, node-modules, mod

Всем здравствуйте!

На "чистом" Debian 11 развернул все необходимые пакеты и стал собирать FreeSwitch 10 с включённым модулем mod_v8.

При выполнении команды `./configure` получаю сообщение: *checking for v8-6.1_static >= 6.1.298... checking for v8fs_static >= 6.1.298... checking for v8 >= 6.1.298... configure: error: You need to either install **libv8-6.1-dev** (>= 6.1.298), **libv8fs-dev** (>= 6.1.298) or disable mod_v8 in modules.conf*

Пакеты libv8-6.1-dev и  libv8fs-dev не ставятся (с таким именем нет). На официальном сайте Debian - https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=bullseye&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libv8-6.1-dev - они не ищутся по любым параметрам.
Я искал пакеты в Debian 11, которые содержат v8, командой: `search v8`

Установил все пакеты из найденных, в которых упоминается v8 и JavaScript: *libv8-dev libnode-dev libnode72 node-babel7-standalone node-clean-css node-get-caller-file node-nan node-to-fast-properties node-v8flags nodejs*

Также установил **libv8 packages**, о которых упоминается вот здесь: https://lists.freeswitch.org/pipermail/freeswitch-users/2021-July/134874.html . Но ошибка сохранилась. Есть ли ещё какая-то команда, которая поможет найти названия пакетов, в которых содержатся необходимые для активации mod_v8 компоненты, о которых упоминается в сообщении: ***libv8-6.1-dev** (>= 6.1.298), **libv8fs-dev** (>= 6.1.298)* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Порядок установки пакетов для Debian 10 (и Debian 11).

1. Качаешь и ставишь на сервере deb-пакеты отсюда (потребуется регистрация):
   https://freeswitch.signalwire.com/repo/deb/freeswitch-1.8/pool/main/libv/

1.1 Для AstraLinux (Debian 10, orel) прописываем права к файлу:

chmod -R 0700 /var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock

2. Инсталлируешь их все (некоторые не установятся, или напишет для AstraLinux, что версия будет иной).

sudo apt install -y ./ПАКЕТ.deb

libv8-6.1_6.1.298-1_bullseye_amd64.deb

libv8-6.1_6.1.298-1_buster_amd64.deb

libv8-6.1_6.1.298-1_stretch_amd64.deb

libv8-6.1-dbg_6.1.298-1_bullseye_amd64.deb

libv8-6.1-dbg_6.1.298-1_buster_amd64.deb

libv8-6.1-dbg_6.1.298-1_stretch_amd64.deb

libv8-6.1-dev_6.1.298-1_bullseye_amd64.deb

libv8-6.1-dev_6.1.298-1_buster_amd64.deb

libv8-6.1-dev_6.1.298-1_stretch_amd64.deb

libv8fs-6.1_6.1.298-1_stretch_amd64.deb

libv8fs-6.1-dbg_6.1.298-1_stretch_amd64.deb

libv8fs-6.1-dev_6.1.298-1_stretch_amd64.deb

3. Если FreeSwitch уже установлен, то раскомменить по пути:
   /usr/local/freeswitch/conf/autoload_configs
   в файле:
   modules.conf.xml
   строку:

   Затем инсталируешь только mod_v8 через (запускаешь из папки сборки FreeSwitch):
   make mod_v8-install
4. Если не установлен, то включаем mod_v8 в файле modules.conf в папке freeswitch (или freeswitch-master), из которой будем всё собирать.
5. В финале запускаешь в консольке FreeSwitch команду (должен быть ответ true):
   load mod_v8